# SWIFTUI....Is it possible with PKCanvasView

Tags: swift, pkcanvasview

I have created a drawing app.  I have the canvas and tools working correctly. I have also added the ability to insert some predefined shapes into the canvas.

My question or where I am running into difficulty is when you use the PKLassoTool() I am unable to size or rotate anything.  I am only able  to move the selected object around.

Is this by design or are there ways to extend the tool to be able to accomplish the size and rotate aspects?

I haven't been able to find anything that would allow me to accomplish the size and rotate aspects of the PKLassoTool().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PKLassoTool: PKTool {
var scale: CGFloat = 1.0  // Scaling factor of the object
var rotation: CGFloat = 0.0  // Rotation angle of the object

func setScale(scale: CGFloat) {
    self.scale = scale
}

func setRotation(rotation: CGFloat) {
    self.rotation = rotation
}
```

}